# Several updates on Case record withing short period of time causing "duplicate value found: <unknown>"

Tags: batch, after-trigger, performance, duplicate-value, mulesoft

I have pretty complex process starting with scheduled Batch Apex, calling my Mulesoft endpoint to retrieve some data and save it on Case record:

1. Batch apex request from Salesforce to Mule is completed and Case is
   updated in SF
2. Case trigger may update CustomObject__c, which may again update the Case record
3. Mule immediately calls another API to retrieve some
   data and uses Salesforce connector to update the same Case
   record.

That means the same case record is updated multiple times within tens of seconds(in batch, via API, trigger).

From time to time attempting update in point 2, Mule service will recieve "**DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: <unknown>**" error.
Admin must then see logs, copy Case payload Mule is trying to update, and update it manually using Salesforce Inspector or Data Loader, which is always successful.

Case and CustomObject__c don't have any custom unique fields, and another objects updated in case trigger does not cause cyclic update of Case.

My main question is:

**Is it possible that multiple updates of the same record may cause duplicate value error, even though it is not violating any uniqe field constraints nor duplicate rules?**

Asking based on this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382298&type=1,
but I am not sure if this applies to my issue or if I am close to 12 actions.

How would You attempt resolving it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: and no other object is updated besides Case and Custom_Object__c ?

Comment: Case trigger may update Cases, Accounts, Quotes, 2 custom objects or create OpportunityShare and AccountShare. None of the objects in transaction have unique fields constraints.

Comment: I could imagine duplicate error on `XXXShare` objects